# Why do I get "second argument to errors.As should not be *error" build error in test only?

Tags: go, go-testing

Consider the following test:

```golang
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestError(t *testing.T) {
    err := &MyError{}
    var target error
    fmt.Println(errors.As(err, &target))
}

type MyError struct{}

func (err *MyError) Error() string {
    return "oops!"
}
```

Running this test returns the build error `second argument to errors.As should not be *error`.

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/dkWS9vPAVz3)

However, when running the exact same code in `main`, then the program runs without issues:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    err := &MyError{}
    var target error
    fmt.Println(errors.As(err, &target))
}

type MyError struct{}

func (err *MyError) Error() string {
    return "oops!"
}
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Rbm_egMt-8i)

I am seeing this behavior in the Go Playground and my local development environment, both of which are using Go 1.20.

Is this a bug in Go?

## Edit

I can work around the build failure in the test by creating an `Error` type:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type Error error // <===== Add error type

func TestError(t *testing.T) {
    err := &MyError{}
    var target Error // <===== Use Error type
    fmt.Println(errors.As(err, &target))
}

type MyError struct{}

func (err *MyError) Error() string {
    return "oops!"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is reported by the `go vet` command.  The `go test` command automatically runs `go vet` to report significant problems.  The `go build` command does not run the `go vet` command.

The warning is not a bug in Go.

There's no purpose in calling [errors.As](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#As) with a `*error` as the second argument because you already know that the first argument satisfies the `error` interface. You are almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that `go test` runs `go vet`, so that must be the answer why I am only seeing this with `go test`. Having said that, the reason why I came across this is because I was looking into how to use `errors.As` in table-driven tests. There is a representative example of what I am trying to do in the [standard library](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/errors/wrap_test.go#L204). Note though that they typed `tc.target` as `any`, and to me it seemed that there shouldn't be a reason why `tc.target` can't be typed as `error` and assign different error types in each test case.

Comment: Your test uses `error` as the type of the target value.  The table in the standard library test stores a pointer to a value of the error type.  The standard library uses `any` instead of `error` because a pointer to an error does not satisfy the `error` interface.  Follow the pattern in the standard library test. Specifically, store a pointer to the target value in the table and pass that value directly to errors.As (do not take address of value in table).